# Creating licence files for a java application?

Tags: java, security, authentication, cryptography, licensing

I am interested in creating a licence file which will authenticate the use of a Java application. The application will open showing a window if the licence is not found or is invalid. I also want to create a licence generator program which I can use (probably obvious) to create licence files. I have no idea how to do this, does anybody have direction as to where I should go or APIs I should be looking at? Thanks in advance.

P.S. I am not interesting is using this for a serious release of a product, I am generally interested in how they are created.

Comment: Basically, it's impossible. In practice, however, you can do it anyway by just making your code so complicated that it's hard for an attacker to figure out how to get around the protection.

Answer (score 3):

On my search for nearly the same "problem" i found this open source project:

[NWTS License Manager](http://java.nicholaswilliams.net/LicenseManager/)

With this libraries I created my own License Generator and implemented the license check in my applications. works!

Also nice docs and examples that would make it clear how it works.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this interesting package. Studying its concept has provided me with several insights. -- When you say it "works", do you mean your intellectual property has not been reverse engineered so far?

Comment: How should you find out if anybody, anywhere in the world does whatever he likes with your software on his own hardware?